# multiple child_process with node.js / socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is more of a design question rather than implementation but I am kind of wondering if I can design something like this. I have an interactive app (similar to python shell). I want to host a server (lets say using either node.js http server or socket.io since I am not sure which one would be better) which would spawn a new child_process for every client that connects to it and maintains a different context for that particular client. I am a complete noob in terms of node.js or socket.io. The max I have managed is to have one child process on a socket.io server and connect the client to it. 
So the question is, would this work ? If not is there any other way in node to get it to work or am I better off with a local server.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js - is single process web platform. Using clustering (child_process), you will create independent execution of same application with separate thread.
Each thread cost memory, and this is generally why most of traditional systems is not much scalable as will require thread per client. For node it will be extremely inefficient from hardware resources point of view.
Node is event based, and you dont need to worry much about scope as far as your application logic does not exploit it.
Count of workers is recommended to be equal of CPU Cores on hardware.

There is always a master application, that will create workers. Each worker will create http + socket.io listeners which technically will be bound to master socket and routed from there.
http requests will be routed for to different workers while sockets will be routed on connection moment, but then that worker will handle this socket until it gets disconnected.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maksims.. So if the child process takes a lot of memory it would be difficult to scale unless we have another server doing load balancing.

Comment: Load Balancing will happen without any problem through all worker. And each worker will be able to handle thousands connections on relatively good hardware. If you still need you can create CPUCores * 4 workers, for example for 4 cores, 16 workers. Then they will be spread over Cores, and there will be no big overhead over memory. But not a worker per connection.
Node is very different from classic blocking platforms, and Node does handle a lot connections on one thread very efficiently.