# Webworkers with a node.js express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-worker

I am new to node.js and am trying to build an express application.
So far, I have setup an app and have created some basic routes.

my entry-point for the application is a file where I am setting up a server with the application:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('main');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

The express app uses mongoose to communicate with the db on appropriate http requests.

At this point, i also need a web-worker which, when the server starts, generate random numbers every 5 seconds and if the generated number is 10, identify it as an event, and store some results in the db.

I am not sure about how to start with this and include it in the structure so far.

I already have the interfaces setup for writing to the db etc. I am just lost with the web-worker implementation and integration part.

Comment: Webworkers are a web technology (ie- run in a browser). Node is a server-side technology and does not support webworkers.  You need to create a browser application and use webworkers there.

Comment: Why do you need to use a webworker for generating random numbers? Why not just use `setInterval()` set for 5 seconds? Also, the code you've posted doesn't really help with your question as it has nothing to do with generating random numbers.

Comment: Just sounds like a job for `setInterval()`.  There are no webWorkers built into node.js.

Comment: I think I used the term Webworker incorrectly. But the code below will solve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In node.js there is no webworkers. But we have something similar called `child_process` (please look documentation for more details : [link](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html))

How to use child_process? There is many materials in stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371439/4138339
there is explanation how in main module run other module (look there for details):
in your main module:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('./othermodulefile');

child.on('message', function(m) {
  // Receive results from child process
  console.log('received: ' + m);
});

// Send child process some work
child.send('Please up-case this string');
```

Or please look this link for addictional description http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_scaling_application.htm
and exaple from that page:
**File: support.js**

```
console.log("Child Process " + process.argv[2] + " executed." );
```

**File: master.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const child_process = require('child_process');

for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
   var workerProcess = child_process.exec('node support.js '+i,
      function (error, stdout, stderr) {
         if (error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
            console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
            console.log('Signal received: '+error.signal);
         }
         console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
         console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
      });

      workerProcess.on('exit', function (code) {
      console.log('Child process exited with exit code '+code);
   });
}
```

Some drawbacks of using child_process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17340465/4138339

> Each thread cost memory, and this is generally why most of traditional
>   systems is not much scalable as will require thread per client. For
>   node it will be extremely inefficient from hardware resources point of
>   view.

and other part:

> Count of workers is recommended to be equal of CPU Cores on hardware.

Other possibility if you need to run some a time-based job scheduler look at this module https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron. It is node.js cron job. installation `npm install cron` and usage example:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. And thank you so much for including the links. Made my life much easier :)